# Error: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo, rowcount

I want to make an insert only if there's no correspondence in the db (mySQL) but he makes me not the statement. Here's the snippet

```
    if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'Non inserisci';
    } else {
        echo 'Inserisci';
        $db->beginTransaction();
        echo 'Ciao3';
        $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO contatti (nome,cognome) VALUES (?,?)") or die('Ciao2');
        echo 'Ciao4';
        $sql->execute(array($_POST['nome'],$_POST['cognome']));
        echo 'Ciao5';
        $db->rollBack();
    }
```

Where The SELECT is

```
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM contatti WHERE nome = ? AND cognome = ? WHERE nome = ? AND cognome = ?") or die ('Ciao1');
    $sql->execute(array($_POST['nome'],$_POST['cognome']));
    $db->rollBack();
```

Can you explain me where's the fault?

Comment: try to count number of tokens

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fault is in arithmetics

Let's count tokens:

```
 SELECT * FROM contatti WHERE nome = ? // one
                       AND cognome = ? // two
                        WHERE nome = ? // three
                       AND cognome = ? // four
```

now let's count number of bound variables:

```
array($_POST['nome'], // one
      $_POST['cognome']) // two
```

4 is apparently not equal to two. that's the problem

Comment: Ok...but i can't do my INSERT anyway. If i do the statement outside the IF it does. Isn't rowCount meaning the same as $mysqli->affected_rows? Thanks

Comment: The underlying fault was in a second `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Username checks out

Answer (score 12):

It seems you have done a little too much copy/paste here:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM contatti WHERE nome = ? AND cognome = ? WHERE nome = ? AND cognome = ?") or die ('Ciao1');
```

should probably just be

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM contatti WHERE nome = ? AND cognome = ?") or die ('Ciao1');
```

<sup>You have had the `WHERE` clause doubled.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Try compare number of declaration in prepare statment with number of definition in bindValue statments

```
$a=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `abc` (`id`, `one`, `two`, `three`) 
VALUES (NULL, :add_one, :add_two, :add_three)");

$a->bindValue(':add_one', $one, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$a->bindValue(':add_three', $three, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

there is no :two statment